# Problems or dangers with automatic remote git fetching?

Tags: git, bash, github

I just started using [bash-git-prompt](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt), which is a bash shell replacement that detects when it's in a git-tracked directory, and if so, can show you how your local branch differs from the remote branch (ahead/behind by X commits), if your local repository is "clean", or if it has staged, conflicted, changed but unstaged, untracked, stashed files.

Just noticed that it periodically (I think default is every 5 min after the local repo is unchanged) runs `git fetch --quiet` to find the remote branch's status.  (Of course, it isn't doing a `pull` or a `merge`.)

Ignoring the increased load on the git server for frequent fetches, is this inviting any problems?

I'm relatively new to git, and not sure if this automatic fetching could complicate development.  Or, if you delay running a merge until you want to, does it really make no difference, except for showing remote status you might otherwise not be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me there is no problem at fetching in the background. That way, you receive commits few by few little after they are pushed. And once you really want to synchronise before merge or rebase, you already have most, if not all the commits and it's a little quicker.

I don't think there is really a performance problem at fetching often because if there is nothing to fetch, the server is doing quite nothing...

I think it's a convenient feature! ;-)

Comment: _You_ may not have a problem with it, but if a thousand users are doing the same, the _server_ you're fetching from might not be so happy.  Just something to keep in mind.